# Convert array into nested object

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Let's say I have the following array:
['product' , 'model', 'version']

And I would like to have an object such as:

```
{
    product: { 
        model: { 
            version: { 

            }
        }
     }
}
```

However, that array is dynamic so it could have 2, 3 or fewer more items.
How can this be achieved in the most efficient way?

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to create just exactly this empty object? Or do you need to merge those keys into an existing objects also containing other keys?

Comment: It can be anything in the value for now as I got access to the data I need to add to this object, but it needs to be within this structure. Tks

Answer (score 15):

Just turn it inside out and successively wrap an inner object into an outer object:

```js
const keys = ['product', 'model', 'version'];
const result = keys.reverse().reduce((res, key) => ({[key]: res}), {});
//                                   innermost value to start with ^^

console.log(result);
```

Comment: `{[key]: res}` --- has this always been a thing? `[key]:value` ?

Comment: Not always. Computed keys exist since ES2016 or so.

Comment: Bear in mind that `keys.reverse` [will mutate the original array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse). Using `keys.reduceRight` ([as suggested below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52081991/1110820)) may be preferable.

Comment: If you want the final "leaf" of your object tree to contain a value other than an empty object, you can use a ternary ```keys.reduceRight((res, key, i) => (i === keys.length - 1 ? {[key]: myValue} : {[key]: res}) , {});```

Answer (score 8):

You can also do it with  [`Array.prototype.reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight):

```js
const result = ['product','model','version'].reduceRight((all, item) => ({[item]: all}), {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood request correctly, this code might do what you need:

```
function convert(namesArray) {
  let result = {};
  let nestedObj = result;
  namesArray.forEach(name => {
    nestedObj[name] = {};
    nestedObj = nestedObj[name];
  });

  return result;
}


console.log(convert(['a', 'b', 'c']));
```

Comment: Worked as expected !! Thanks for your help!!